# Eigenvalue of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A =  \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 &  1 & 0 \\
1 &  0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}

I want to find the eigenvalue of this matrix A.
I know how to find its eigenvalues by using rule of Sarrus, and they are 2,1 and 0.
But I believe there is definitely a easier method to get its eigenvalue.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one specific case where eigenvectors are easier to spot.
Note that  $A$ sends the vector $(x,y,z)^T$ to $(x+z, y, x+z)^T$. In the special case $x=z=0$, namely the vector $e_2$ goes to itself, so 1 is an eigenvalue. Another special case $x=z, y=0$, for example $(1,0,1)^T$ goes to $(2,0,2)^T$ which is twice the input, hence 2 is an eigenvalue. Also the matrix is singular (two of its rows are same) and so 0 is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Can I ask you what do you mean by " A sends the vector transpose of (x,y,z) to transpose  (x+z, y, x+z)?

Comment: Every $m\times n$ matrix $M$ is a function (more specifically a linear transformation) that sends all vectors $v$ of  size $n$ to vectors of size $m$ by matrix multiplication: $ v\mapsto Mv$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the characteristic polynomial approach

$$|A - \lambda I | = 0 \implies -\lambda ^3+3 \lambda ^2-2 \lambda = 0 \implies -(\lambda -2) (\lambda -1) \lambda = 0 \implies \lambda_{1,2,3} = 0, 1, 2 $$

If you are looking for iterative methods, see the [*list*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Iterative_algorithms) of methods.

Comment: I know that. But I want to find a easier way to calculate the eigenvalue.

Comment: A =  \begin{vmatrix}
1-λ & 0 & 1 \\
0 &  1-λ & 0 \\
1 &  0 & 1-λ
\end{vmatrix} I know this. But how did you get that −λ3+3λ2−2λ=0 so fast? Thank you

Comment: did you used that the method to calculate the determinant of 3x3 matrix? I thought you did some simplification of A so that you can get that equation so fast.

Comment: Yes, is is very fast, try it since two values are zero, it is only two multiplications and then a very simple factorization to arrive at the reduced char. poly.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you want some method for finding the eigenvalues without using what Amzoti did, here is one approach.

It is rather quick to see that $$\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{matrix}\right]=\left[ \begin{matrix} a+c \\ b \\ a+c \end{matrix}\right]$$  Then we want $\lambda a= a+c$, $\lambda b=b$, $\lambda c=a+c$.  The only solutions to the middle equation are $\lambda=0,1$ or $b=0$; combining the first and last tells us that $a=c$ when $\lambda\neq 0$, and thus $2a=\lambda a$.  When $a,c\neq 0$, this gives us the final eigenvalue 2.